# How to fix 'javah' error when using NDK with Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, sdk, android-ndk

I am trying to set up NDK so that I can add C/C++ code to my Android application within Android Studio 0.5.1. I am ultimately trying to get it compiled during gradle build, and to properly handle APKs generation. Much like the tutorial explains in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=okLKfxfbz40 . My first step of the entire process was downloading Android SDK.

However, I am running into the error:

```
'javah' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.
```

after typing in the command:

```
 javah -d jni -classpath C:\Android\sdk\platforms\android-   

 19\android.jar;..\..\build\classes\debug com.example.ndksample.MainActivity
```

I have troubleshooted briefly online leading me to try downloading Java™ Platform, Standard Edition Development Kit (JDK) again. Nothing fixed. Can someone explain why I receive this error? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set java Environment Variables -> System Variables,
add the following variables.

**JAVA_HOME**

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144
```

**CLASSPATH**

```
%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib
```

and modify the Path as -

**Path**

```
%JAVA_HOME%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;
```

now Restart PC.

Answer (score 1):

i suggest pointing cmd to the path where the javah file is located 
i.e: path\javah [switches]
hope that helped!

Comment: can you describe it in more detail?